# How to fix "ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception." with telegram.ext.dispatcher?

Tags: discord.py, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I downloaded bot which copy messages from telegram group and sending to my discord channel.

But when I am trying to send a message in a group, I am getting this error.

```
2022-12-31 08:25:19,877 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 557, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 199, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "C:\Discord-Telegram-Bot-main 1\main.py", line 46, in getTgAnnouncement
    textUpdate = update.channel_post.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I am using python 3.10
Python-telegram-bot 13.15

Below i will add the code

```
import requests
import json
import asyncio
import os
import json
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater,CallbackContext,MessageHandler,Filters
from telegram.utils import helpers
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async

load_dotenv('token.env')
discordToken = os.getenv('DCTOKEN')# discord bot token
telegramToken = os.getenv('TGTOKEN')# telegram bot token
discordChannelId = os.getenv('DCCID')# discord announcement channel id
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="k!",
    case_insensitive=True,
    intents=discord.Intents.all(),
    help_command=None
)

async def sendDcAnnouncement(textUpdate,nonTextUpdate):
    announcementChannel = bot.get_channel(int(discordChannelId))
    if textUpdate != None and nonTextUpdate != None:
        await announcementChannel.send(textUpdate,file=discord.File(nonTextUpdate))
        os.remove(nonTextUpdate)
    elif textUpdate == None:
        await announcementChannel.send(file=discord.File(nonTextUpdate))
        os.remove(nonTextUpdate)
    elif nonTextUpdate == None:
        await announcementChannel.send(textUpdate)

def getTgAnnouncement(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    textUpdate = None
    nonTextUpdate = None
    updateType = helpers.effective_message_type(update)

    if updateType == 'text':
        textUpdate = update.channel_post.text
    else:
        textUpdate = update.channel_post.caption
        if updateType == 'photo':
            nonTextUpdate = update.channel_post.photo[-1].get_file()['file_path']
        elif updateType == 'video':
            nonTextUpdate = update.channel_post.video.get_file()['file_path']     
        elif updateType == 'document':
            nonTextUpdate = update.channel_post.document.get_file()['file_path']
        elif updateType == 'voice':
            nonTextUpdate = update.channel_post.voice.get_file()['file_path']
    loop.create_task(sendDcAnnouncement(textUpdate,nonTextUpdate))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'logged in as {bot.user}')
    updater = Updater(token=telegramToken,use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                        level=logging.INFO)
    getTgAnnouncement_handler = MessageHandler((~Filters.command),getTgAnnouncement)
    dispatcher.add_handler(getTgAnnouncement_handler)
    updater.start_polling()

bot.run(discordToken)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I expect that this bot will send messages and that I will not get these errors.

Answer (score 1):

`MessageHandler` handles all updates that have one of the fields `message`, `edited_message`, `channel_post` or `edited_channel_post`. So in `getTGAnnouncement`, it may very well be the case that `update.channel_post is None`.

If you want that handler to only handle `channel_post` update, please use [`Filters.update.channel_post`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.channel_post).

---

As a side note: I see that you're using `python-telegram-bot` v13.x. Support for that version [is ending soon](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotchannel/129) in favor of the new v20.x.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: added 'update.channel_post = None
but nothing changed..

Comment: I in now way implied that adding the line `update.channel_post = None` would solve your issue. Please carefully re-read my answer.